# Django User's user.get_profile() is not working while running on apache

Tags: python, django, apache, django-users

I am facing a weird problem. While I am running my python server using `python manage.py runserver` I get my user.get_profile() working and everything seems to be fine, but when I am running the same application from apache server + mod wsgi setup I am getting this `AttributeError` error : `'User' object has no attribute 'get_profile'`. I have no clue what should I do.

wsgi.py

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "passportpay.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    operator_id = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Comment: Could you show your wsgi.py ? and your model ¿

Comment: Sure, this all what I have in my wsgi.py

`import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "passportpay.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
`

Comment: added it with the question

Comment: Please don't post screenshots: code is just text and can be posted as such.

Comment: Sorry @DanielRoseman. Added code in text

Comment: models.py and wsgi.py added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_profile` was [removed in Django 1.7](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/releases/1.7/#features-removed-in-1-7), having been deprecated since version 1.5.

You should make sure you are running the same version of Django in production as in development. In the longer term, you should rewrite your code so as not to use get_profile.

Comment: I am using virtual env for running it with apache. Both the versions are same. I am using 1.6 in both the places.

Comment: Are you 100% sure? Can you do python manage.py shell and import django and do import django django.get_version()?

Comment: >>> django.get_version()
'1.6'

Comment: pip install django still gives you the version 1.6 and that's what I did.

Comment: No it doesn't. If you have 1.6 installed, as you presumably do locally, it won't upgrade it (unless you pass `--upgrade`). But if you don't have anything installed, it will install the latest release, which is 1.7.

Comment: Well, I am not very sure. But I am sure 1.6 is what I have got.

Comment: I am sorry dude, it's 1.7. I was checking on my local system, but my virtual env has 1.7. Sorry.. _/\_